# Looking for sci-fi movie featuring dragons vs Navy

Tags: story-identification, dragons, trailer

Looking for movie featuring Dragons vs. Navy (or Army, but the trailer featured battleship trying to shoot the dragons down).

Trailer also showed a dogfight between helicopters and dragons, capping (on the trailer) with a dragon setting a Blackhawk's blades on fire.

Comment: which time period the movie was relased or which location the plot has set

Comment: Was released this year or last one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw that trailer too and then could not find it again , but stumbled across it today ,it is called Crimson Skies

Only other info i could find on this is that it was originaly called Dragon seige but your guess is as good as mine as to wether its movie or game

Comment: Can you add some more information on this? All links on IMDB point to the very unrelated (and very awesome) XBox game from the early 2000's.

Comment: This looks like to be a game and not a movie. Maybe the OP was confused, and you're right. But as far as movies go, this looks doubtful.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds similar to [Dragon Wars : D-War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-War), although I haven't found a specific trailer (of which there are quite a few) with a Blackhawk's blades on fire. Plenty of dragons destroying helicopters in other ways though. Here is a [short trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi3466789145), and here is a [longer trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnQXvQ1R4gg). Some of the dialogue in the longer trailer is Korean, but the movie itself is mostly in English.

[image: Dragon-vs-copter]

Comment: i guess so it would be D-war

Comment: @KevinTheKnight *Maybe*, we'll see. If you have a different guess, post it. My answer failed to meet *all* the criteria, and it's been too long since I watched the movie to remember if it had a helicopter with the blades on fire. It fits enough that it's worth a try. If you've got a guess, by all means, *please post.*

Comment: No, it'd not D-War. All helicopters that appear are Apaches, for one.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very like the British film [Reign of Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reign_of_Fire_%28film%29), which included several scenes of fire-breathing dragons versus helicopters.

The trailer is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wg7bjwEXp7Y) and although there are various helicopter shots there's nothing specifically with the blades on fire.

Comment: Except Reign of Fire is 12 years old, which doesn't fit the timeframe the questioner added after you posted this one.  Awesome movie though, and 100,000 times better than D-war.

Comment: That is true.If it helps, the movie was released this year. Or last one, at the latest.

Comment: *Reign of Fire* is only good with the [RiffTrax commentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk965nFMuSA), in my opinion.

Comment: I like hearing it at least once without the RiffTrax before going wild with it.

Answer (score 1):

MainStay Productions released a trailer on YouTube last year, about a movie project they are working on with BluFire Studios, ostensibly called Crimson Skies.
The premise is that a volcanic island erupts,  releasing thousands of dragons from millenia-long slumber, that attack a small fleet of Navy vessels.

I checked on both MainStay and BluFire's websites, neither of which make any mention of the project, which makes me think that the trailer may simply be a "pitch demo" to try and find a studio willing to underwrite it. There is no other mention of the movie, other than the video, that I can find.

Of course, this may also be just another elaborate YouTube hoax.